# Why does setting this referenced object to NULL not reset all copies of it?

Tags: php, class, oop

Why does `$assigned` not become NULL when we assigns NULL to `$instance`? When we change the value of `$var` via `$instance->var`, `$assigned` obtains the new updated value.

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$instance   = new SimpleClass();
$assigned   =  $instance;
$reference  =& $instance;

$instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';

$instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null

var_dump($instance);
var_dump($reference);
var_dump($assigned);
```

Output:

```
NULL
NULL
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) {
   ["var"]=>
     string(30) "$assigned will have this value"
}
```

I am using PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: "Why does $assigned not become NULL when we assigns NULL to $instance?" Because they are two completely different variables, and $assigned neither knows nor cares what you do to $instance.

Comment: You have been provided with one of the best answers on this site for a long time - care to respond to the author, or at least accept it?

Comment: Following on from your not replying to me, or the excellent answer below, I have downvoted.

Answer (score 8):

## The basics

To understand what happens, you need to dig into php's internals and see how memory is managed.

Under the hood, a value is represented like this:

```
+--------------------+
| (type) {{ VALUE }} |
| refcount = a       |
| isref = b          |
+--------------------+
```

The reference counter `a` counts the number of variables pointing to this value. The `isref` flag shows whether the value was assigned by value (i.e. `$a = VALUE`) or by reference (i.e. `$a =& VALUE`).

Let's assume the following case:

```
                 +--------------------------+
$a ------------->| (int) 58                 |          $a = 58
                 | refcount = 1 ; isref = 0 |
                 +--------------------------+
```

If you copy the value of `$a` into `$b`, PHP just increments the `refcount` in order to be memory-efficient (i.e. do not store twice the same value):

```
                 +--------------------------+
$a -------+----->| (int) 58                 |          $b = $a
          |      | refcount = 2 ; isref = 0 |
          |      +--------------------------+
          |
          |
$b -------+
```

If you change the value of $b to something else, a new value is created and the refcount to `58` is decremented:

```
                 +--------------------------+
$a ------------->| (int) 58                 |          $b = 'hello'
                 | refcount = 1 ; isref = 0 |
                 +--------------------------+

                 +--------------------------+
$a ------------->| (string) 'hello'         |
                 | refcount = 1 ; isref = 0 |
                 +--------------------------+
```

In case of a reference, the `isref` flag is set to `true`, and a change impacts both identifiers:

```
                 +--------------------------+
$a -------+----->| (int) 58                 |          $b =& $a
          |      | refcount = 2 ; isref = 1 |
          |      +--------------------------+
          |
          |
$b -------+
```

.

```
                 +--------------------------+
$a -------+----->| (int) 21                 |          $b = 21
          |      | refcount = 2 ; isref = 1 |
          |      +--------------------------+
          |
          |
$b -------+
```

## About object references

You can often hear that in PHP, objects are passed by reference transparently. [According to the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), it's not entirely true. The name identifier `$a` contains an *object identifier*, and that's what's passed between functions. I'll illustrate this identifier with an integer of type `object` below, I have no idea of how it's really done under the hood, but the explanation holds ;-)

Not to confuse the *identifier*, i.e. the variable name with the *object identifier*, i.e. the number of the object in memory.

```
                 +--------------------------+
$a ------------->| (object) 547654764237685 |          $a = new FooBar();
                 | refcount = 1 ; isref = 0 |
                 +--------------------------+
```

Somewhere else in memory, PHP stores the `FooBar` instance we just created with identifier `547654764237685`. When you use the value `(object) 547654764237685`, PHP automatically retrieves said object and allows you to use it transparently.

## So what happened ?

Let's review your code line by line.

You first create a new `SimpleClass` instance.

```
                 +--------------------------+
$instance ------>| (object) 547654764237685 |          $instance = new SimpleClass();
                 | refcount = 1 ; isref = 0 |
                 +--------------------------+
```

Then you make a value assignment to `$assigned`, i.e. increment the `refcount`:

```
                 +--------------------------+
$instance ---+-->| (object) 547654764237685 |          $assigned = $instance;
             |   | refcount = 2 ; isref = 0 |
             |   +--------------------------+
             |
             |
$assigned ---+
```

The third line references `$reference` to `$instance`. Because the `refcount` of the value is greater than one and because it's not already a reference (`isref = 0`), PHP creates a new similar value in memory:

```
                 +--------------------------+
$instance ---+-->| (object) 547654764237685 |          $reference =& $instance;
             |   | refcount = 2 ; isref = 1 |
             |   +--------------------------+
             |
             |
$reference --+

                 +--------------------------+
$assigned ------>| (object) 547654764237685 |
                 | refcount = 1 ; isref = 0 |
                 +--------------------------+
```

The three identifiers `$instance`, `$assigned` and `$reference` evaluate to the very same object, because the object identifier stays the same. Although, we now have two distinct values in memory for it.

This is why the call `$instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';` impacts `$instance->var`, `$assigned->var` and `$reference->var`.

Now when you set `$instance` to `null`, because `$reference` references the same value, both are impacted:

```
                 +--------------------------+
$instance ---+-->| (NULL)                   |          $instance = null;
             |   | refcount = 2 ; isref = 1 |
             |   +--------------------------+
             |
             |
$reference --+

                 +--------------------------+
$assigned ------>| (object) 547654764237685 |
                 | refcount = 1 ; isref = 0 |
                 +--------------------------+
```

The object reference of `$assigned` is not impacted, because it's a separate value, thus `$assigned` still calls the object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because object itself is still intact after assigning its identifier a null value.

When you set an object's field - it resides in object's part of memory, but when you set its "pointer" another value - it resides somewhere else, so the object itself is still there and can be referenced by another identifier (pointer).

Here's a ref: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)